# how to add 30 minutes to current time

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to add 30 minutes to the current time.

I tried this

```
NSDate *dateToFire = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5*60];
```

BUt just need the time
like 10:00:30   ---> +30 = 10:30:00

Suggestions are always appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` work?

Comment: You shold not hard code by 1800 or 60*5 because of leap seconds and all. Always follow dateComponents...as i posted this is easy safe and tested API from Apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this way:

```
NSCalendar *calendar=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components=[NSDateComponents new];
components.minute=30;
NSDate *newDate=[calendar dateByAddingComponents: components toDate: [NSDate date] options: 0];
//To get date in  `hour:minute` format.
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterHHMM=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatterHHMM setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSString *timeString=[dateFormatterHHMM stringFromDate:newDate];

NSLog(@"===> %@",timeString);
```

Comment: ==> 2013-01-12 08:08:35 +0000  this is the result,which i think is right, but i need to get the hour:minutes only. DO i need to break the string ?how?

Answer (score 3):

Please add it like this: 30*60. You are adding just 5 mins in your code.

The time that you are adding is in mili seconds.

So you need to try this:

```
NSDate *dateToFire = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:30*60];
```

This will add 30 minutes in the current time.

Comment: actually log show dateToFire 2013-01-12 08:06:25 +0000 and i just need 08:06

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
NSDate *dateToFire = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:1800.0];
```

Hopefully, It'll help you.
Thanks.