# How to add minutes to custom time in swift2

Tags: ios, swift

What I do is:

[How to add minutes to current time in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465205/how-to-add-minutes-to-current-time-in-swift)

[how to add 30 minutes to current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291271/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-current-time)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 endFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
 let endTimeString = "2017-01-16 12:58:56"
 let endTime = endFormatter.dateFromString(endTimeString)
 endTime?.dateByAddingTimeInterval(180) // 3 Minute
 print(endTime)
```

1st answer @rob i tried that one but failed . second answer suggest `dateByAddingTimeInterval` i am not suer is it is work or not .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `dateByAddingUnit` as @Rob doing instead of `dateByAddingTimeInterval`. The reason you are not getting correct time is may because of `TimeZone` so try to set `timeZone` with your `NSDateFormatter` instance.

```
endFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
endFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
let endTimeString = "2017-01-16 12:58:56"
let endTime = endFormatter.dateFromString(endTimeString)

//Now add the 3 minute in endTime

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let date = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Minute, value: 3, toDate: endTime, options: [])
```

Comment: i accept your answer  with in  2 minute  could you tell me please why i don't use **dateByAddingTimeInterval**  and  when need to use  **dateByAddingTimeInterval**

Comment: i am not sure .. i did getting any thing there .. could you help just a single line .

Comment: @cristanlika `dateByAddingTimeInterval` will not give you correct date in case of day-light savings where as `dateByAddingUnit` will give you the perfect one.

Comment: Using `dateByAddingTimeInterval` to add seconds, minutes or even hours is actually no problem. 3 minutes are *always* 180 seconds, no matter what the time zone or calendar is. What the referenced link states is that a day (or month, year, ...) is not a fixed time interval, and *then* you have to do the proper calendar calculations. – But there is no reason to avoid `dateByAddingTimeInterval` completely.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateWithMinuteInterval = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(minute: 23), to: endTime)!
```

Comment: sorry my mistake that not current time .. time come from server and that is string format

Comment: So simply convert your string time to date, and then ass it as a parameter here.

Comment: yea you are  right i convert from string to date : let endTime = endFormatter.dateFromString(endTimeString)